# Untyped channel in golang

Tags: go, channel, untyped-variables

I'm writing some package, where channel is only used to interrupt some process, so it is never read any value, just detects that it need to stop, like this:

```
func myfunc(stop_chan chan /*bool*/) {
  for {
    //do something time consuming
    // ....
    // check on channel
    select{
      case <-stop_chan:
        //cleanup
        return
      default:
    }
    // continue working
  }
}
```

later I wish this function to accept any type of channel. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

> I wish this function to accept any type of channel. Is that possible?

No, this is not possible. There are no untyped channels in Go. You could accept a channel of any type, using `interface{}`, then using reflection to interact with that channel. But this is cumbersome and slow, so not recommended.

A better approach, probably, is to settle on a single type of channel (`chan struct{}` is the natural choice for your use-case), or use a [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) variable instead, which can handle cancellation in a standardized way.

Comment: Could you please give some plain example? I'm new to go.

Comment: Tried to cast like this: myfunc( chan interface{}(exit_ch)) but get compilation error. On myfunc declaration channel type is interface{}

Comment: Go doesn't have casting at all. Aside from that, a type assertion like that in a function signature makes no sense anyway.

Comment: Which do you want an example of? My suggestion is to use a context. For that, I suggest this [Go blog article](https://blog.golang.org/context) for examples and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To create a channel that does not actually transmit any data beyond the fact that a message has been sent, do it like this:

```
stop_chan := make(chan struct{})

go func() {
  // do something time consuming
  // ....

  stop_chan <- struct{}{}
}()

for {
  // check on channel
  select{
    case <-stop_chan:
      //cleanup
      return
    default:
  }
  // continue working
}
```

This will send an empty/anonymous struct over the channel to signal to the `select`.

See "1-to-1 notification by sending a value to a channel" in https://go101.org/article/channel-use-cases.html for a more complete example and explanation.